# unexpected result in bit shifting operation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I think the answer is straight forward but still I am not getting it.

```
byte a=5;
int b=10;
int c=a>>2+b>>2;
System.out.print(c);
```

As `a>>2` is `1` and `b>>2` is `2`, I am expecting output to be `3` but is `0`. What's the reason?

Comment: Addition has [higher precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than bitwise shifts

Comment: You can always use parentheses if you have doubts about the order of execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

What you do is the same as

```
int c=(a>>(2+b))>>2;
```

You want this :

```
int c=(a>>2)+(b>>2);
```